# ¿De qué me sirve marcar como favorita una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, favoritos

He visto que existe el famoso botón de estrellita en las preguntas. Una vez lo usé porque quería estar informado de la respuesta que dieran a dicha pregunta, sin embargo, marcarla como favorita no me sirvió de mucho.

¿Podría alguien decirme qué sentido tiene y explicármelo bien?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En tu perfil tienes una pestaña de `Favoritos` en la cual se encuentran las preguntas que has marcado como favoritas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto te permite realizar el seguimiento de una pregunta de tu interés de una manera mucho más cómoda y sencilla.

El concepto es el mismo que cuando guardas una página web en tu navegador para poder acceder a ella de una manera mucho más rápida.